Current Over an Arrow in CircuiTikZ
I am trying to draw the following inverting op-amp circuit:

After attempting, this is the result I got:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{
    tikz,
    circuitikz
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}    
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8]
    \draw
    (0,0) to[R=\(R_{1}\), *-] ++(3,0) coordinate(A)
    to[short] ++(1,0)
    node[op amp, noinv input down, anchor=-, fill=cyan!20](OA){\texttt{OA}}
    (OA.out) to[short, -*] ++(1.5,0) coordinate(D)
    (OA.+) -| ++(-1,-1) node[ground](B){}
    (A) |- ++(0,1) to[short, i=\(I_{2}\)] ++(1,0)
    (A) |- ++(1,1) to[R=$R_2$] ++(2,0) -| (OA.out)
    (B) to[short, -*] ++(5.5,0) coordinate(E)
    (B) to[short, -*] ++(-3,0) coordinate(C)
    (0,0) to[open, V^<=\(V_{\mathrm{in}}\)] (C)
    (D) to[open, V^>=\(V_{\mathrm{out}}\)] (E)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


However, I haven't included the first current because I ran out of ideas on how to add it. Does anybody know how to achieve that? Might as well suggest ways to improve the code, in case there's a better way to do it. This is my first time using TikZ, hence CircuiTikZ. So I hope anyone can help me! I would really appreciate it.

Since my question above is answered, I have an additional question. I don't know where to put this, so let me know if I misplaced my question. My question is, compared to the circuit above, does the following circuit behave the same? Let aside the more notations it has.

If so, how to draw the double-ticked arrow for the input and output voltages?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your code snippet to be compilable. Then we do not have to uess what you are doing ...

Hello! Thanks for letting me know. I have edited it. @Mensch

I would organize the circuit differently, but look at the suggestions in the comments of the following code.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%% You have to choose a voltage direction (see manual)
%%% It seems you want straight voltages.
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw
        %% an unadorned "short" is the same as --
        %% you can use the `i=` in the bipole definition.
        %% Try `f=` if you prefer external arrows
        (0,0) to[R=\(R_{1}\), *-, i=$I_1$] ++(3,0) coordinate(A) -- ++(1,0)
        node[op amp, noinv input down, anchor=-, fill=cyan!20](OA){\texttt{OA}}
        (OA.out) to[short, -*] ++(1.5,0) coordinate(D)
        %% you **need** the connection dot when there are more than three wire in a node
        (OA.+) -| ++(-1,-1) node[ground](B){} node[circ]{}
        (A) -- ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp) to[R=$R_2$, i=$I_2$] (OA.out|-tmp) -- (OA.out)
        (B) to[short, -*] ++(-3,0) coordinate(C)
        %% (E) is found going horizontally from B and vertically from D
        (B) to[short, -*]  (B-|D) coordinate(E)
        %% this (in input) is a generator, NOT a short --- your code worked
        %% by sheer luck
        (0,0) to[V^<=\(V_{\mathrm{in}}\)] (C)
        %% you do NOT want a generator here (different circuit --- and broken)
        %% lowercase `v`
        (D) to[open, v_<=\(V_{\mathrm{out}}\)] (E)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Please notice for future questions that my code snippet is complete; that is, you can just copy, paste, and compile it. Please try to do the same in your future questions

Your explanation is constructive! Thank you so much. Also, I have edited the code snippet as suggested. Will do it for my future questions!

Hello! I just updated my question. Kindly check it, I would truly appreciate it if you could help me again. :-)

@vszuvszu Please, please don't do that. It destroys how this site works: one question, one answer, so that it will be useful not just for you, but for other people also. Ask another question if you have another question, it's free!

Btw, the double arrows make no sense at all. How do you specify the voltage polarity there? (And yes, the circuit is obviously the same). Moreover, the second question feels more a question for electronics SE, not for here...

I see ... Thank you for enlightening me! I will keep that in mind.
